# Unconfirmed transaction almost 5days waiting :(

Tags: transactions

Anyone could help me this is my first time
{
"Version": "1",
"LockTime": "0",
"Vin": [
{
"TxId": "f766b698554f5fd23ba0ad4efce5d39eef4242609dd11a6feebb496af5d5bb5d",
"Vout": "20",
"ScriptSig": {
"Asm": "304402205025420f7d7ff0601baa2d208e54442f44ec6ad11f506ed0fb7e5ebd555d1d3d02204659c608dc031e653c729619cc4138b4fb811c9b8f6013564a651f3008e83d8f[ALL] 03beeb2aa4b2afc2601a54aa3e9b02e75dcc9ab53d6135c83317327cb3c165e739",
"Hex": "47304402205025420f7d7ff0601baa2d208e54442f44ec6ad11f506ed0fb7e5ebd555d1d3d02204659c608dc031e653c729619cc4138b4fb811c9b8f6013564a651f3008e83d8f012103beeb2aa4b2afc2601a54aa3e9b02e75dcc9ab53d6135c83317327cb3c165e739"
},
"CoinBase": null,
"TxInWitness": null,
"Sequence": "4294967295"
}
],
"Vout": [
{
"Value": 0.04616479,
"N": 0,
"ScriptPubKey": {
"Asm": "OP_HASH160 4b87b8e34b41ceb6e4de7d716b153187e75e0f86 OP_EQUAL",
"Hex": "a9144b87b8e34b41ceb6e4de7d716b153187e75e0f8687",
"ReqSigs": 1,
"Type": "scripthash",
"Addresses": [
"38aPC5NBgWUWzV9Ccaro5ePhxfn5vQDZyj"
]
}
}
],
"TxId": "4587a71a9bbf4038d2479a7496e05119c5d6972f3d5ad70f04222368428e5fce"
}

Comment: Hi James, the Bitcoin network is somewhat backlogged at the moment. Your transaction was sent with a feerate of 8 satoshi/byte and the network is currently requiring 70 satoshi/byte to get into a block. It might take a few days for your tx to confirm. The question that I linked you to explains it more comprehensively.

Comment: Next time I will explain it nicely it was just my first time and it almost 6days still not confirm.

Comment: It's alright, we get that it's a bit confusing for people that just discover Bitcoin. We created that linked question because we tend to get a dozen or so of similar questions like yours in a week like this. :) I hope the linked question helped you understand better what's happening.